# Python dependencies(wordcloud) installed but still triggers errors

Tags: python, dependencies, environments

I am trying to create a wordcloud with Python so I tried so many times to install the wordcloud with `pip install wordcloud` and finally succeeded. https://ibb.co/hYuzP7
When I run the `pip list`  I can see it listed there. 
https://ibb.co/hUhm47 You can see the Python version I am using too.
I thought that because I have installed Anaconda may confuse between the two environments, but the wordcloud is installed on my Python 3.6 and this is what I am using in my IDE. https://ibb.co/kYJern
Does anyone know what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by naming your local module **wordcloud.py** - exactly as the external library you are trying to import your class from. Therefore, python tries to import this class from your local module in C:\Users\Desktop...\FYP\worldcloud.py. Simply changing the name of your .py file should fix this issue.